# Nginx rewrite pipe character to encoded character

Tags: nginx

I need to rewrite **|** to **%7C** in

```
/api/foo.json?stuff=true&things=false&fields=id,Name|rename(name)&_dc=12345
```

I've tried numerous different ways with no luck, it might be possible that there's multiple pipe characters too.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: This is tagged nginx, but that doesn't make much sense. What are you actually trying to do? Where do you think this rewrite is going to live? Where did the pipe originally come from?

Answer (score 0):

nginx `rewrite` directive matches only the normalized URI, which in your case is `/api/foo.json`. You need to handle the processing of query arguments with `if` statements and regular expressions.